# Ansible: Different values to the same variable in a config file for different hosts

Tags: redis, ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I'm setting up a Redis cluster for my webservers, which I want for 1 of them to be a master and the other 3 to be slaves. 
Due this, I must have two different .config files for the different servers, the slaves with the line `slaveof <host> <port>` and the master without this line.

So it would be something like:

```
## master_server /etc/redis.conf
bind 0.0.0.0
port 6379
etc...

## slave_server1 /etc/redis.conf
bind 0.0.0.0
port 6379
slaveof masters_ip_address 6379
etc...

## slave_server2 /etc/redis.conf
bind 0.0.0.0
port 6379
slaveof masters_ip_address 6379
etc...

## slave_server3 /etc/redis.conf
bind 0.0.0.0
port 6379
slaveof masters_ip_address 6379
etc...
```

This is the way I was trying to do:

First I set two variables in the defaults main file:

```
## /defaults/main.yml
redis_slave: 'masters_ip_address 6379'
redis_master: ''
```

And then added a `false` variable to my *group_vars*, which is on top of priority, so all of the servers would inherit this value, and also added the same variable to the *host_vars* correspondent to the server that I want to be the master, but `true`, so only this server would have a different value to the `slaveof` variable:

```
## /group_vars/webservers.yml
master: false

## /host_vars/master_server.yml
master: true
```

And in my template I implement the if-else logic to set the right values:

```
## redis.conf.j2
{% if master == false %}
  {% set slaveof = redis_slave %}
{% else %}
  {% set slaveof = redis_master %}
{% endif %}

slaveof {{ slaveof }}
```

But when I try to test this playbook it sets the same .config file for all of the servers. Am I missing something or is there another easier way to do this?

Comment: there seems to be a typo in the question : `## /host_vars/master_server.yml` should be `group_vars/master_server.yml`

Comment: No, that's right. master_server is within the webservers group. As the priority of variables is host > child group > parent group > all groups, I want only this master_server.yml to have a different value from all of the other servers. So I set a global variable for all of the webservers group with the same value, and change it only in the master_server.

Comment: it seems to me this would be better done by just defining groups `redis_masters` and `redis_slaves` and then setting the variable `master` accordingly in each of the `group_vars`.

Comment: I >>think<< I got your point but I don't quite follow, can you be a bit clearer?

Comment: Sorry :) Let me write an answer instead, where I can express myself better with syntax and so on. You can vote and comment on it then.

Comment: Sure! I appreciate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to conditionally template a configuration file, based on some aspect of the host. You create a variable to describe this aspect (whether the host is a master or a slave in a Redis configuration) -- `master`.

Then you rightly use the conditional check on this variable to

```
## templates/etc/redis.conf.j2
{% if master == false %}
  {% set slaveof = redis_slave %}
{% else %}
  {% set slaveof = redis_master %}
{% endif %}

slaveof {{ slaveof }}
```

This could be done easier by defining two groups for redis configuration:

```
# inventory.ini
.
.
.
[redis_masters] # defines group redis_masters
master.server.ip
[redis_slaves]  # defines group redis_slaves
slave.server.ip

[redis_hosts:children]
redis_masters
redis_slaves
```

Now you define the relevant `group_vars`:

```
# group_vars/redis_slaves.yml
slaveof: redis_master

# group_vars/redis_masters.yml
slaveof: redis_slave

#group_vars/redis_hosts.yml
# all the generic Redis stuff
bind: 0.0.0.0
port: 6379
```

Comment: I see your point. But I only have one group (webservers) which contain all of the servers that I want to work with (1 master + 3 slaves)

Comment: This use of one group is the source of your problems though. A group is just a "logical" grouping, a "tag" if you will, allowing you to give certain variables and values to some hosts and others to other hosts. By calling your redis slaves "redis slaves" -- ie, putting them in a redis-slaves group, it will be easier to understand _why_ they have that variable set in such a way, and you can move some logic out of the template, to make it cleaner.

Comment: great! This should work for you :) Could you also accept the answer if it solves your problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! And of course I can. Again, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: It's amazing how many problems can be solved by getting the inventory design right, and how many are created by getting the inventory design wrong.